# Display list of site collections

Tags: site-collection

I'm currently working on a Project Management System.
Is there a way that I could list all projects which were created as site collections?

https:server/projects/project1
https:server/projects/project2
https:server/projects/project3

I want to show on this link https:server/ something like this:

- Project 1 - Project 1 Description
- Project 2 - Project 2 Description
- Project 3 - Project 3 Description

Comment: online or in onpremises

Comment: it's on-premise

Answer (score 0):

You could use Powershell to get your list of site collections.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Get-SPWebApplication http://yourwebapp.com | Get-SPSite | Select ID, Url | Out-File -FilePath "D:\spSites.txt"
```

Then using the output you could create a list where end users could access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use server object model to get all site collection.

```
private List<SiteUrl> GetApplicationWebs()
    {
        List<SiteUrl> siteList = new List<SiteUrl>();

        SPWebApplication webApp = GetWebAppCollection(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
        foreach (SPSite site in webApp.Sites)
        {
            site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
            if (site != null)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    siteList.Add(new SiteUrl(web.Title, web.Url, web.Webs.Count));

                }
            }
        }


        return siteList;

    }
```

[Also can refer link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1bf690c9-797d-4270-835e-07ea439015a6/how-to-retrieve-list-of-all-site-collections?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Answer (score 0):

Search could also be an option , set the query to "path:https:server/projects/ Contentclass:STS_Site"